# Difference between inorganic and organic semiconductors: electronic structure or configuration, or?

Tags: terminology, semiconductor-physics

Organic semiconductors differ from inorganic semiconductors. In organic semiconductors the molecules are held together by weak van der Waals interactions and in inorganic semiconductors by covalent bonds. So the bonds are different. How do you express the main difference between the twos? Is it the electronic structure or rather the electronic configuration, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am an undergraduate physics student working on device physics of organic semiconductors in a chemistry lab.

From my elementary understanding, there is a big difference in charge transport of these two semiconductors. In bulk (inorganic) semiconductors, I believe that charge normally flows (not sure what this means), where as in organic semiconductors charges "hop" from one available state to another.

The properties of devices made from organic vs inorganic semiconductors are VERY different. This I know from experience.

1.) Organic Devices are generally much cheaper and easier to fabricate

2.) Organic semiconductors generally have much lower mobility (performance essentially) than inorganic Semiconductors. The crystalline structure of inorganics allows for an efficient well defined path for the charges to travel, whereas organic polymers will naturally twist and bend and turn.

3.) Organic semiconductors (polymers) are flexible. Inorganic semiconductors are inflexible.

4.) Processing conditions for inorganic semiconductors are generally much more rigorous and sensitive than organic semiconductors.